# Check if on last page of paginated post using wp_link_pages

Tags: pagination, wp-link-pages

A client of mine reviews products on his site, and wants to display the review criteria and score on the last page of each posts. Typically, there are 3-5 pages per post, and I'm looking for a way to check if we're on the last page.

‹!--nextpage--› is used in the post to divide it into pages, and wp_link_pages on the front-end to display pagination links.

I've been able to find ways of checking if we're on page one, or not on page one, or on a specific page. But nothing for checking if we're on the very last page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this info in the global vars `$multipage`, `$numpages`, and `$page`

```
global $multipage, $numpages, $page;
if( $multipage && $page == $numpages )
    echo 'last page';
```